# Apache2 - strange sh process in htop?

Tags: centos, apache2, zombie-process, htop

The server is cent os with apache2+php configured. Sometimes the pages are getting locked. Too much time to respond.

While checking htop in server found strange processess. All values are zero for this "sh" processes.

Can't find how it got created?[image: Htop of sh processess]

Comment: Can you explain what you're hosting? Pure PHP-applications or also something else via CGI-BIN?

Comment: Mod_wsgi is there too

Comment: Without any details about the setup and what is triggering new shells there isn't much to gone on to resolve this except saying something under the apache user is generating a lot of zombie processes. Most likely this is a web application that is being exploited.